# I don't know how I can change the "square" here based on the exponent I insert. If it's 3 I want to print "cube" and so on. Could you help guys. Thx

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
def generator(base1, exponent1):
    u = base1 ** exponent1
    return u

base = int(input("Enter the base number: "))
exponent = int(input("Enter the exponent: "))

print("The *square* of the number", base, "is", generator(base, exponent))
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what were your results? For example, a dictionary mapping the integer with the string representation you're trying to replace? An f-string to do the actual printing?

Comment: What if exponent is 4,5,6... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create a dictionary to store the `square` and the `cube`. If it exists, then the value is fetched, or `raised to ... power` will be formatted:

```
dict1={2:'squared',3:'cubed'}

print(f"The base {dict1.get(exponent) if exponent in dict1 else f'raised to {exponent}th power'}, is, {generator(base, exponent)}")
```